# How can I know whether my CPU shares the vector registers among the cores or each core has its private ones?

Tags: multithreading, cpu-architecture, simd, cpu-registers, xeon-phi

How can I know whether my CPU shares the vector registers among the cores or each core has its private ones?

Where can I get the references?

I hope to use multi-threading and SIMD to optimise my program's floating-point computation. Will they cause any conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your comments in another reply, it appears you're referring to the Xeon Phi. If I understand correctly, you're asking if each thread has its own private set of vector registers? The answer is yes!

To clarify a little further, the Xeon Phi has about 50 cores each with their own register file. Internally each core supports simultaneous multithreading (SMT) so the register file is shared among threads however there will be *at least* 4x16 512-bit logical vector registers per core. If you choose to use SMT, there won't be any conflicts with respect to the registers but there might be conflicts with respect to the vector functional units. The idea is that you can switch between threads within the same core when one is waiting a cache miss or something similar.

**Edit to answer your question: What is SMT?**

The Xeon Phi has 50 physical in-order cores. Each core has its own L1 instruction cache, data cache and two functional units. In a traditional design the core would fetch two adjacent instructions in a thread from the i-cache and try to execute them on the two available functional units. One common problem that made this technique inefficient occurred when executing load instructions where the data was not present in the d-cache. The processor would have difficulty finding instructions to send to its functional units since subsequent instructions very often depended on the data being loaded.

SMT is a technique to help alleviate this. It gives each core just enough extra structure to manage additional threads efficiently. In the Xeon Phi, the logical register file and program counter are replicated four times. Most other structures like the caches and functional units can remain more of less the same. Now when there is a d-cache miss, the processor will start fetching another thread's instructions and send them to the functional units where they operate on that thread's subset of registers. This way it can find work to do when waiting for main memory without the high overheads of a full context switch.

To summarise: You might see 200 cores on your Xeon Phi but in reality only 50 of those are working in parallel at any given time, the rest just switch threads really quickly.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the 'vector functional units' stuffs? Thx.

Comment: I can try. I've edited my answer above. Don't forget to upvote and choose a response that answers your question.

Comment: Intel Hyperthreading is not switch-on-stall, it actually alternates front-end cycles between non-stalled threads.  The reason Xeon Phi uses 4-way SMT instead of 2-way on their big-core chips (e.g. Skylake) is to better hide FP latency without large out-of-order exec resources.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading#Taxonomy - switch-on-stall is coarse-grained.  Intel's actual implementation is fine-grained: round-robin the front-end, competitively share the register file and scheduler, with instructions from different threads able to dispatch to execution units in paralle.

Answer (score -1):

As far as the developper is concerned each "core" is a processor, it just so happens to be on the same die. Anything you may be concerned with is abstracted in the hardware and / or os at the thread level.

Comment: I don't understand. Optimise for the hardware would be meaningless if it is all abstracted and nothing should be cared. Actually if vector registers are provided with each core, it'd end up with different optimizations according to my knowledge.

Comment: No what i mean is, multiple cores on one die is the same as multiple actual processors as far as the developper is concerned, if you're really interested in the détails (and assuming you're talking about X86/64) you can get the intel manuals but the questions you're asking are way out of the bounds of what you're trying to do, when you use multi threading and / or simd you don't need to know if you're working with cores or separate physical processors, it's the same from a programmer standpoint, usually the only thing you need to know is 1 : how many physical threads can run concurrently

Comment: and 2 how many more than that you need to be CPU bound, you don't specifically need to worry about how registers are set yourself, now if you tell us what you're trying to do in a more specific way (what language, what application type etc) i can go in more détails but globally the answer is a cpu core is the same as a separate processor for a programmer, it's only different physically (same die) and even on the same processor threads don't "share" registers, that's handled by the OS which saves them / switches to the other process / switches back and restore them

Comment: So as a programmer, use those registers and don't worry about where or what they are as that's not at your level it's handled but at the OS level (basically, if instead of each having their own set of register they shared them, which would make no sense, that would still be abstracted by the OS which would make sure each of your threads, even if you have 100 threads for only 2 cores, has their own register values)

Comment: Ok, I'm using C++ OpenMP and if needed I can use inline assembly. x86_64. (Intel Xeon E5 with Xeon Phi)

Comment: I should be more specific. If I hope to get some information on these categories, where can I get it? And for Intel manuals, probably I hope to get some guide on where to look for that information because they are too huge.

Comment: intel manuals are only useful if you're working really close to the hardware level, it's certainly not needed just because you plan to use a few inline assembly instructions in an OpenMP program (and you probably don't need to do that at all either, you're most likely better off letting a mix of libraries and the compiler do the work, typically much better performance Wise than trying to handcraft assembly). If you want an answer to a question however you'll need to clarify the question as trying to use C++ OpenMP has nothing to do with figuring out anything about registers